# JavaのMath.ulp(Math.nextAfter)をdartに移植したい。

Tags: java, dart

Dartで特殊な距離計算をするためのロジックをJavaから移植しているのですが、
DartにはMath.ulpに当たるものが無いため、自力で実装中です。

グーグル先生に教えてもらった
以下のStackOverflowの回答を参考にしています。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104763/how-to-compute-ulpwhen-math-ulp-is-missing

```
/*
 * use a precalculated value for the ulp of Double.MAX_VALUE
 */
private static final double MAX_ULP = 1.9958403095347198E292;

/**
 * Returns the size of an ulp (units in the last place) of the argument.
 * @param d value whose ulp is to be returned
 * @return size of an ulp for the argument
 */
@Override
public double ulp(double d) {
    if (Double.isNaN(d)) {
        // If the argument is NaN, then the result is NaN.
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    if (Double.isInfinite(d)) {
        // If the argument is positive or negative infinity, then the
        // result is positive infinity.
        return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }

    if (d == 0.0) {
        // If the argument is positive or negative zero, then the result is Double.MIN_VALUE.
        return Double.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    d = Math.abs(d);
    if (d == Double.MAX_VALUE) {
        // If the argument is Double.MAX_VALUE, then the result is equal to 2^971.
        return MAX_ULP;
    }

    return nextAfter(d, Double.MAX_VALUE) - d;
}

@Override
public double copySign(double x, double y) {
    return com.codename1.util.MathUtil.copysign(x,y);
}

private boolean isSameSign(double x, double y) {
    return copySign(x, y) == x;
}

/**
 * Returns the next representable floating point number after the first
 * argument in the direction of the second argument.
 *
 * @param start starting value
 * @param direction value indicating which of the neighboring representable
 *  floating point number to return
 * @return The floating-point number next to {@code start} in the
 * direction of {@direction}.
 */
@Override
public double nextAfter(final double start, final double direction) {
    if (Double.isNaN(start) || Double.isNaN(direction)) {
        // If either argument is a NaN, then NaN is returned.
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    if (start == direction) {
        // If both arguments compare as equal the second argument is returned.
        return direction;
    }

    final double absStart = Math.abs(start);
    final double absDir = Math.abs(direction);
    final boolean toZero = !isSameSign(start, direction) || absDir < absStart;

    if (toZero) {
        // we are reducing the magnitude, going toward zero.
        if (absStart == Double.MIN_VALUE) {
            return copySign(0.0, start);
        }
        if (Double.isInfinite(absStart)) {
            return copySign(Double.MAX_VALUE, start);
        }
        return copySign(Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(absStart) - 1L), start);
    } else {
        // we are increasing the magnitude, toward +-Infinity
        if (start == 0.0) {
            return copySign(Double.MIN_VALUE, direction);
        }
        if (absStart == Double.MAX_VALUE) {
            return copySign(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, start);
        }
        return copySign(Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(absStart) + 1L), start);
    }
}
```

のコードのうち、

> Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(absStart) + 1L

の箇所のやっている意味がいまいちわからず
そもそもが基礎的な部分以外、僕はbit演算を理解できていなく
またDartではdouble <> long bit　変換が存在しないので作業が止まってしまいました。

１．なぜlong bitに起こして±1してdoubleに戻しているのですか？
　doubleをlongに置き換えてるのは小数点の表現を整数に変換しているのかなと思うので
　その処理系の浮動小数点も含めた最下桁を±1するってことかな？って思いましたがそれで正しいのでしょうか？
２．そしてこれをDartで実現する場合の勘所など。

についてどなたか教えてください。

Comment: IEEE754 (https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) についてはどのくらい理解していますか？ ulp とはつまり仮数部の最小差ってことで、なので仮数部を１動かしたいわけなのです。（という説明で理解できるには IEEE754 の理解が必須だったりして）

Comment: @774RR ありがとうございます！忙殺されてこちらの作業がストップしていますが、熟読します。（仮数部という言葉久々に聞きましたが多分想像していたような事をしているのですね！）

Answer (score 1):

今更なんですが自力実装はやめてJavaのコードをDartから呼び出す方法を考えたほうが良いのではないでしょうか。
https://flutter.keicode.com/basics/method-channel-java.php
この手のライブラリを自力で実装するとそちらの実装とバグ取りが作業の大半になってしまうように思います。

Comment: せっかく頂いたアドバイスですがこの度の質問はflutterでなくdartへの移植です。ただFlutterでの実装の際には参考にさせていただきます！